# Plot function with integral: find the right formula

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

How can I plot a function like this?

[image]

Where `r_A` and `n_A,0` are constant. For now, let's leave out the details: I just want to know what equation I should write as the argument of the `\addplot` command.

Any idea?

P.S. don't know why the text within $ isn't parsed as TeX

Comment: Just draw a smooth curve specify list of points no need for a formula.

Comment: As for the rendering, maybe read: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/47927